# My Telegram bot doesn't receive emoji message reactions

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new in developing Telegram bots and I'm trying to handle message emoji reactions in my Kotlin bot.

The main idea of my bot is handle reactions and delete message when desired reaction is received

I use telegrambots-spring-boot-starter:6.5.0 and my `onUpdateReceived` method looks like this:

```
    override fun onUpdateReceived(update: Update) {
    println("event!")
}
```

It work fine with handling messages, but when I react on message nothing happens.

Comment: My bot is added as administrator to group chat. I also granted him all rights in BotFather. And it still doesn't get any message reactions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it turns out that the Update objects via the official bot API don't contain `messageReactions` as found in the Telegram API (yet?): https://core.telegram.org/api/reactions.
So, for now this just seems to be impossible via the official bot API.